# TextBlock Inlines - Add/Remove Item At Method?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, textblock

Why **Inlines** class doesn't have methods like AddItemAt(string, index) - in case I want to style or RemoveItemAt(index)?

Comment: I'm using .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: Which type is `TextBlock.Inlines` ? Did you check the MSDN on that type ?

Comment: I've checked, but I was confused about TextElementCollection<TextElementType> parameter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.documents.inlinecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) InlineCollection contains InsertBefore, InsertAfter, Insert, RemoveAt

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't paying attention really good. Should I remove this question ?

Comment: @Kapparino no reason to delete it :)